# How to change the JavaScript context in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When using DevTools, there is an option to change the [JavaScript context](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#context), as can be seen in the image below. When selecting one of these contexts, certain variables can now be accessible that weren't previously in the top context.

[image]

I want to make a program in JavaScript that interacts with the variables that can only be seen in these contexts, like the one highlighted in the image, which is not an IFrame. So how is one able to do it with puppeteer? Using `page.frames().find`, like suggested [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4529), doesn't seem to work properly in this case.

Comment: For extensions you probably want to look in browser.pages() not page.frames()

Comment: @pguardiario Didn't know about that, thanks! Though it could be extensions, that is not the case, unfortunately.